# Quicker Query from Excel thru ADO to SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, excel, vba, ado

I've developed something to help some of the supervisors in our call center pull their own reports. This code pulls the data, places it into an Excel table and then that table is used to do calculations on the sheet that they can actually see. However, when I added the subquery with the openquery statements, it slowed down from taking a few seconds to taking a few minutes in SSMS as well as in Excel. Does connecting to a linked server with an openquery statement really slow it down that much? Or is there something in my query slowing it down?

Note: I currently don't have permission to view the execution plan, so I can't see exactly what is slowing it down.

Thanks in advance!

```
Dim objConn As New ADODB.Connection
Dim objRecordset As New ADODB.Recordset
Dim drpPicker As DropDown
Dim strDropVal As String
Dim strSQL As String
Dim tblData As ListObject

Set tblData = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data").ListObjects("cs")
tblData.DataBodyRange.Rows.Delete

Set drpPicker = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Dashboard").DropDowns("dropFis_Month")
strDropVal = Format(drpPicker.List(drpPicker.ListIndex), "mmm-yyyy")

strSQL = "" & vbNewLine
strSQL = strSQL + "select" & vbNewLine
strSQL = strSQL + "    case" & vbNewLine
strSQL = strSQL + "        when emp.intCallCenterID=10 then 'Dallas'" & vbNewLine
strSQL = strSQL + "        when emp.intCallCenterID=1 then 'Tracy'" & vbNewLine
strSQL = strSQL + "        when emp.intCallCenterID=2 then 'Ohio'" & vbNewLine
strSQL = strSQL + "    end as 'Call Center'," & vbNewLine
strSQL = strSQL + "    sup.strCsrFirstName+' '+sup.strCsrLastName as 'Supervisor'," & vbNewLine
strSQL = strSQL + "    emp.intempid as 'ID'," & vbNewLine
strSQL = strSQL + "    emp.strCsrFirstName+' '+emp.strCsrLastName as 'Name'," & vbNewLine
strSQL = strSQL + "    fis.ISODate as 'Date'," & vbNewLine
strSQL = strSQL + "    calls as 'Calls'," & vbNewLine
strSQL = strSQL + "    held_calls as 'Held Calls'," & vbNewLine
strSQL = strSQL + "    handle_time as 'Handle Time'," & vbNewLine
strSQL = strSQL + "    talk_time as 'Talk Time'," & vbNewLine
strSQL = strSQL + "    acw_time as 'ACW Time'," & vbNewLine
strSQL = strSQL + "    hold_time as 'Hold Time'," & vbNewLine
strSQL = strSQL + "    ring_time as 'Ring Time'," & vbNewLine
strSQL = strSQL + "    aux_time as 'AUX Time'," & vbNewLine
strSQL = strSQL + "    rona as 'RONA'," & vbNewLine
strSQL = strSQL + "    aux.personaltime/86400 as 'AUX-Personal'," & vbNewLine
strSQL = strSQL + "    COUNT(rls.avayadate) as 'Released Calls'," & vbNewLine
strSQL = strSQL + "    isnull(sched.sched_time,0) as 'Scheduled Time'," & vbNewLine
strSQL = strSQL + "    isnull(xep.sched_xptn,0) as 'Exceptions'," & vbNewLine
strSQL = strSQL + "    isnull(qa.qa_earned,0) as 'QA Points Earned'," & vbNewLine
strSQL = strSQL + "    isnull(qa.qa_possible,0) as 'QA Points Possible'" & vbNewLine
strSQL = strSQL + "from" & vbNewLine
strSQL = strSQL + "    (" & vbNewLine
strSQL = strSQL + "    select" & vbNewLine
strSQL = strSQL + "        sum(CallsHandled) as 'calls'," & vbNewLine
strSQL = strSQL + "        SUM(heldcalls) as 'held_calls'," & vbNewLine
strSQL = strSQL + "        sum(acdtime+acwtime+holdtime) as 'handle_time'," & vbNewLine
strSQL = strSQL + "        sum(ACDTime) as 'talk_time'," & vbNewLine
strSQL = strSQL + "        sum(ACWTime) as 'acw_time'," & vbNewLine
strSQL = strSQL + "        sum(HoldTime) as 'hold_time'," & vbNewLine
strSQL = strSQL + "        sum(ringtime) as 'ring_time'," & vbNewLine
strSQL = strSQL + "        sum(auxtime) as 'aux_time'," & vbNewLine
strSQL = strSQL + "        sum(redirectnoans) as 'rona'," & vbNewLine
strSQL = strSQL + "        employee_id," & vbNewLine
strSQL = strSQL + "        AvayaDate" & vbNewLine
strSQL = strSQL + "    from" & vbNewLine
strSQL = strSQL + "        reporting.dbo.phones" & vbNewLine
strSQL = strSQL + "    Group by" & vbNewLine
strSQL = strSQL + "        employee_id," & vbNewLine
strSQL = strSQL + "        AvayaDate" & vbNewLine
strSQL = strSQL + "    ) fone" & vbNewLine
strSQL = strSQL + "    join ccat.dbo.tblEmployees emp on emp.intEmpID=fone.employee_id" & vbNewLine
strSQL = strSQL + "    join ccat.dbo.tblEmployees sup on sup.id=emp.intSupervisorID" & vbNewLine
strSQL = strSQL + "    join FiscalCal fis on Fis.isodate=fone.AvayaDate" & vbNewLine
strSQL = strSQL + "    left join phones_auxes aux on aux.employee_id=emp.intEmpID and aux.AvayaDate=fis.ISODate" & vbNewLine
strSQL = strSQL + "    left outer join reporting.dbo.agent_releases rls on rls.avayadate=Fis.ISODate and rls.employee_id=emp.intEmpID" & vbNewLine
strSQL = strSQL + "    left outer join (" & vbNewLine
strSQL = strSQL + "    select" & vbNewLine
strSQL = strSQL + "        s.id as 'sched_id'," & vbNewLine
strSQL = strSQL + "        s.employee_id as 'sched_emp'," & vbNewLine
strSQL = strSQL + "        s.schedule_date as 'sched_date'," & vbNewLine
strSQL = strSQL + "        DATEDIFF(ss,s.start_time,s.end_time) as 'sched_time'" & vbNewLine
strSQL = strSQL + "    from" & vbNewLine
strSQL = strSQL + "        reporting.dbo.Schedules s" & vbNewLine
strSQL = strSQL + "    Group by" & vbNewLine
strSQL = strSQL + "        s.schedule_date," & vbNewLine
strSQL = strSQL + "        s.employee_id," & vbNewLine
strSQL = strSQL + "        s.start_time," & vbNewLine
strSQL = strSQL + "        s.end_time," & vbNewLine
strSQL = strSQL + "        s.ID" & vbNewLine
strSQL = strSQL + "    ) sched on sched.sched_date=fis.ISODate and sched.sched_emp=fone.employee_id" & vbNewLine
strSQL = strSQL + "    left outer join (" & vbNewLine
strSQL = strSQL + "    select" & vbNewLine
strSQL = strSQL + "        schedule_id as 'sched_id'," & vbNewLine
strSQL = strSQL + "        SUM(duration)as 'sched_xptn'" & vbNewLine
strSQL = strSQL + "    from" & vbNewLine
strSQL = strSQL + "        reporting.dbo.violations" & vbNewLine
strSQL = strSQL + "    where" & vbNewLine
strSQL = strSQL + "        isapproved = 0" & vbNewLine
strSQL = strSQL + "    Group by" & vbNewLine
strSQL = strSQL + "        schedule_id" & vbNewLine
strSQL = strSQL + "    ) xep on xep.sched_id=sched.sched_id" & vbNewLine
strSQL = strSQL + "    left outer join (" & vbNewLine
strSQL = strSQL + "    select" & vbNewLine
strSQL = strSQL + "        cast(cast(eval.eval_datetime as date) as datetime) as 'qa_date'," & vbNewLine
strSQL = strSQL + "        prsn.personnel_id as 'qa_emp'," & vbNewLine
strSQL = strSQL + "        sum(eval.form_total) as 'qa_earned'," & vbNewLine
strSQL = strSQL + "        sum(eval.form_possible) as 'qa_possible'" & vbNewLine
strSQL = strSQL + "    from" & vbNewLine
strSQL = strSQL + "        openquery ( jeffqms ,'select * from witness.dbo.evaluations' ) eval" & vbNewLine
strSQL = strSQL + "        join openquery ( jeffqms ,'select * from witness.dbo.person' ) prsn ON eval.person_pk = prsn.person_pk" & vbNewLine
strSQL = strSQL + "    where" & vbNewLine
strSQL = strSQL + "        prsn.personnel_id is not null" & vbNewLine
strSQL = strSQL + "        and prsn.login_name is not null" & vbNewLine
strSQL = strSQL + "        and eval.calibration != 'T'" & vbNewLine
strSQL = strSQL + "        and prsn.personnel_id not like 'TestUser'" & vbNewLine
strSQL = strSQL + "        and prsn.personnel_id not like 'IT'" & vbNewLine
strSQL = strSQL + "    Group by" & vbNewLine
strSQL = strSQL + "        personnel_id" & vbNewLine
strSQL = strSQL + "        ,cast(cast(eval.eval_datetime as date) as datetime)) qa on qa.qa_date=fis.ISODate and qa.qa_emp=emp.intEmpID" & vbNewLine
strSQL = strSQL + "where" & vbNewLine
strSQL = strSQL + "    (emp.intCallCenterID=10 or emp.intCallCenterID=1 or emp.intCallCenterID=2)" & vbNewLine
strSQL = strSQL + "    and fis.FIS_MM_YYYY='" & strDropVal & "'" & vbNewLine
strSQL = strSQL + "    and emp.strStatus='active'" & vbNewLine
strSQL = strSQL + "    and (emp.intcscdeptid=14 or emp.intcscdeptid=19) " & vbNewLine
strSQL = strSQL + "Group by" & vbNewLine
strSQL = strSQL + "    Fis.ISODate," & vbNewLine
strSQL = strSQL + "    emp.intEmpID," & vbNewLine
strSQL = strSQL + "    emp.strCsrFirstName," & vbNewLine
strSQL = strSQL + "    emp.strCsrLastName," & vbNewLine
strSQL = strSQL + "    sup.strCsrFirstName," & vbNewLine
strSQL = strSQL + "    sup.strCsrLastName," & vbNewLine
strSQL = strSQL + "    emp.intCallCenterID," & vbNewLine
strSQL = strSQL + "    fone.calls," & vbNewLine
strSQL = strSQL + "    fone.held_calls," & vbNewLine
strSQL = strSQL + "    fone.handle_time," & vbNewLine
strSQL = strSQL + "    fone.talk_time," & vbNewLine
strSQL = strSQL + "    fone.acw_time," & vbNewLine
strSQL = strSQL + "    fone.hold_time," & vbNewLine
strSQL = strSQL + "    fone.ring_time," & vbNewLine
strSQL = strSQL + "    fone.aux_time," & vbNewLine
strSQL = strSQL + "    fone.rona," & vbNewLine
strSQL = strSQL + "    aux.personaltime," & vbNewLine
strSQL = strSQL + "    sched.sched_time," & vbNewLine
strSQL = strSQL + "    xep.sched_xptn," & vbNewLine
strSQL = strSQL + "    qa.qa_earned," & vbNewLine
strSQL = strSQL + "    qa.qa_possible" & vbNewLine
strSQL = strSQL + "Order by" & vbNewLine
strSQL = strSQL + "    [Call Center]," & vbNewLine
strSQL = strSQL + "    Supervisor," & vbNewLine
strSQL = strSQL + "    Name," & vbNewLine
strSQL = strSQL + "    fis.ISODate"

objConn.Open "Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Initial Catalog=database_name;Data Source=server_name;UID=user_name;PWD=password"

With objRecordset
    .ActiveConnection = objConn
    .Open Source:=strSQL
End With

ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data").Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset objRecordset

objRecordset.Close
Set objRecordset = Nothing
objConn.Close
Set objConn = Nothing
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you really need every column (*) from witness.dbo.evaluations?

I would add some of the details in your subquery Where clause **inside** the OpenQuery select statement within the quotes and restrict it to exactly the columns needed. This will result in more being done at the jeffqms server and less data coming back over the wire.

For example in your code above

```
select" & vbNewLine
strSQL = strSQL + "        cast(cast(eval.eval_datetime as date) as datetime) as 'qa_date'," & vbNewLine
strSQL = strSQL + "        prsn.personnel_id as 'qa_emp'," & vbNewLine
strSQL = strSQL + "        sum(eval.form_total) as 'qa_earned'," & vbNewLine
strSQL = strSQL + "        sum(eval.form_possible) as 'qa_possible'" & vbNewLine
strSQL = strSQL + "    from" & vbNewLine
strSQL = strSQL + "        openquery ( jeffqms ,'select * from witness.dbo.evaluations' ) eval" & vbNewLine
strSQL = strSQL + "        join openquery ( jeffqms ,'select * from witness.dbo.person' ) prsn ON eval.person_pk = prsn.person_pk" & vbNewLine
strSQL = strSQL + "    where" & vbNewLine
strSQL = strSQL + "        prsn.personnel_id is not null" & vbNewLine
strSQL = strSQL + "        and prsn.login_name is not null" & vbNewLine
strSQL = strSQL + "        and eval.calibration != 'T'" & vbNewLine
strSQL = strSQL + "        and prsn.personnel_id not like 'TestUser'" & vbNewLine
strSQL = strSQL + "        and prsn.personnel_id not like 'IT'" & vbNewLine
```

"eval.calibration != 'T'", "prsn.personnel_id not like 'TestUser'" and "prsn.personnel_id not like 'IT'" could be put inside the openquery 'select' statement to restrict rows earlier.

Also, why not put the entire join between eval and person in one openquery statement to save two trips to jeffqms.

```
openquery ( jeffqms ,'select column, column, column from witness.dbo.evaluations join witness.dbo.person where blah blah' )
```

I always find in the few instances I've had to use openquery, do as much as you can on the remote server first.